# Google Analytics custom event push thru Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have Google Tag Manager account created, 
And I have Google Analytics account created,

Inside my app I only have GTM included, and after some research, I managed to connect my Google Analytics acc with GTM to track page views.

Now, what I used to do before with just using GA, I was using some custom events inside my app,

So `ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');`

Now I tried to do the same after GTM is connected but I'm not getting any events inside my admin

I also tried doing `dataLayer.push` with same event arguments and event is still not showing up

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm missing to get custom events working?

Also, I don't want them to be defined inside GTM (that would mean that for every custom event I need to create a trigger if I get it right)

Is it possible to just publish them without any configuration inside GTM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Analytics Tag (type `event`), Trigger and some dataLayer Variables, you can find the guidelines here: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679219?hl=en

Comment: Is it possible to send all custom events and their parameters dynamically instead of defining them one by one in GTM?